# Listen to multiple ports from one server

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it possible to bind and listen to multiple ports in Linux in one application?

Comment: yes that is possible, you need to use `select` or threads though

Comment: Yes.

The best answer to these types of questions is for you to write up a small test application and *try it yourself*.

As you become more experienced, you'll find yourself more often writing these little "test programs" to figure things out.

Comment: How is it possible with select? I'm not sure how to do many binds for one socket

Comment: It's not one socket. It's multiple sockets.

Comment: Thx Jonathon. Your explanation (kind of) makes sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For each port that you want to listen to, you:

1. Create a separate socket with `socket`.
2. Bind it to the appropriate port with `bind`.
3. Call `listen` on the socket so that it's set up with a listen queue.

At that point, your program is listening on multiple sockets.  In order to accept connections on those sockets, you need to know which socket a client is connecting to.  That's where `select` comes in.  As it happens, I have code that does exactly this sitting around, so here's a complete tested example of waiting for connections on multiple sockets and returning the file descriptor of a connection.  The remote address is returned in additional parameters (the buffer must be provided by the caller, just like accept).

(`socket_type` here is a typedef for `int` on Linux systems, and `INVALID_SOCKET` is `-1`.  Those are there because this code has been ported to Windows as well.)

```
socket_type
network_accept_any(socket_type fds[], unsigned int count,
                   struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen)
{
    fd_set readfds;
    socket_type maxfd, fd;
    unsigned int i;
    int status;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    maxfd = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        FD_SET(fds[i], &readfds);
        if (fds[i] > maxfd)
            maxfd = fds[i];
    }
    status = select(maxfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (status < 0)
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    fd = INVALID_SOCKET;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (FD_ISSET(fds[i], &readfds)) {
            fd = fds[i];
            break;
        }
    if (fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    else
        return accept(fd, addr, addrlen);
}
```

This code doesn't tell the caller which port the client connected to, but you could easily add an `int *` parameter that would get the file descriptor that saw the incoming connection.

Comment: I was wondering if this can happen without select / poll, but probably no way.

Answer (score 3):

You only `bind()` to a single socket, then `listen()` and `accept()` -- the socket for the bind is for the server, the fd from the `accept()` is for the client. You do your select on the latter looking for any client socket that has data pending on the input.

Comment: btw, did you delete your answer to my question or did a mod do it? Kind of crazy that they did if so, the comments attached were useful info that someone else could have used.

Comment: nope... wasn't me. I thought that was a pretty good conversation myself. :-/

Comment: yeah, it was helpful, even to know what doesn't work...mods are crazy here; maybe you can edit it to incorporate some of our discussion and ask for it to be undeleted? you could even say that we've tried all this and that doing a magic number is the best alternative to all of that, so it'd be a legit answer that i could accept (since that looks to be the real answer anyway) up to you, I don't really mind either way. I was probably just going to write my own answer anyway to that effect, because the one given so far doesn't address my issue really.

Comment: if you can't undelete you could write a new answer too and I'll accept it unless/until a better one shows up...kind of sucks to lose the comments though...you're probably in a better spot to write the answer too since I don't have the comments to view anymore (forgot what all was covered)

Answer (score 2):

In such a situation, you may be interested by [libevent](http://libevent.org/). It will do the work of the `select()` for you, probably using a much better interface such as `epoll()`.

The huge drawback with `select()` is the use of the `FD_...` macros that limit the socket number to the maximum number of bits in the `fd_set` variable (from about 100 to 256). If you have a small server with 2 or 3 connections, you'll be fine. If you intend to work on a much larger server, then the `fd_set` could easily get overflown.

Also, the use of the `select()` or `poll()` allows you to avoid threads in the server (i.e. you can `poll()` your socket and know whether you can `accept()`, `read()`, or `write()` to them.)

But if you really want to do it Unix like, then you want to consider `fork()`-ing before you call `accept()`. In this case you do not absolutely need the `select()` or `poll()` (unless you are listening on many IPs/ports and want all children to be capable of answering any incoming connections, but you have drawbacks with those... the kernel may send you another request while you are already handling a request, whereas, with just an `accept()`, the kernel knows that you are busy if not in the `accept()` call itself—well, it does not work exactly like that, but as a user, that's the way it works for you.)

With the `fork()` you prepare the socket in the main process and then call `handle_request()` in a child process to call the `accept()` function. That way you may have any number of ports and one or more children to listen on each. That's the best way to really very quickly respond to any incoming connection under Linux (i.e. as a user and as long as you have child processes wait for a client, this is instantaneous.)

```
void init_server(int port)
{
    int server_socket = socket();
    bind(server_socket, ...port...);
    listen(server_socket);
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; ++c)
    {
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if(child_pid == 0)
        {
            // here we are in a child
            handle_request(server_socket);
        }
    }

    // WARNING: this loop cannot be here, since it is blocking...
    //          you will want to wait and see which child died and
    //          create a new child for the same `server_socket`...
    //          but this loop should get you started
    for(;;)
    {
        // wait on children death (you'll need to do things with SIGCHLD too)
        // and create a new children as they die...
        wait(...);
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if(child_pid == 0)
        {
            handle_request(server_socket);
        }
    }
}

void handle_request(int server_socket)
{
    // here child blocks until a connection arrives on 'server_socket'
    int client_socket = accept(server_socket, ...);
    ...handle the request...
    exit(0);
}

int create_servers()
{
    init_server(80);   // create a connection on port 80
    init_server(443);  // create a connection on port 443
}
```

Note that the `handle_request()` function is shown here as handling one request. The advantage of handling a single request is that you can do it the Unix way: allocate resources as required and once the request is answered, `exit(0)`. The `exit(0)` will call the necessary `close()`, `free()`, etc. for you.

In contrast, if you want to handle multiple requests in a row, you want to make sure that resources get deallocated before you loop back to the `accept()` call. Also, the `sbrk()` function is pretty much never going to be called to reduce the memory footprint of your child. This means it will tend to grow a little bit every now and then. This is why a server such as Apache2 is setup to answer a certain number of requests per child before starting a new child (by default it is between 100 and 1,000 these days.)