# How do I make a server listen on multiple ports

Tags: python, sockets

I would like to listen on 100 different TCP port with the same server. Here's what I'm currently doing:-

```
import socket
import select

def main():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    for i in range(1000,1100):
        server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', i))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    read_list = [server_socket]
    while True:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(read_list, [], read_list)
        for s in readable:
            if s is server_socket:
                #print "client connected"
                client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
                read_list.append(client_socket)
            else:
                # One of the tcp clients
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not result:
                    s.close()
                    read_list.remove(s)
                    #print "client disconnected"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It returns an error saying `Permission Denied`. Is it because some ports(1000-1100) are reserved and are not allocated to it or because of some other reason?

I tried with (8000-8100) and it says `Invalid Arguments`

**EDITED**

```
import socket
import select

def create_socket(TCP_PORT):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', TCP_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    return server_socket


def main():

    read_list = []

    for TCP_PORT in range(8000,8100):
        read_list.append(create_socket(TCP_PORT))

    while True:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(read_list, [], read_list)
        for s in readable:
            if s is server_socket:
                #print "client connected"
                client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
                read_list.append(client_socket)
            else:
                # One of the tcp clients
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not result:
                    s.close()
                    read_list.remove(s)
                    #print "client disconnected"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. Ports [below 1024](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only) are reserved. (You'll need special privileges, e.g. root privileges to bind to such a port).
2. A socket can only listen at one port. So to listen to several port, you need to create one socket per port.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. As I thought, 1000-1100 must be reserved and hence permission was denied. Talking on 2nd point!!! It means that to listen on 100 different ports, I need to make 100 different socket objects?

Comment: which means do I need to do it manually, writing the same LOC again and again or can I loop around it as well?

Comment: Sure, you can use a loop where you create a socket and bind it. Save the return value of the socket() call in a list, which you pass to select()

Comment: Will it be something like this? I've edited my question with the solution that I'm currently doing. Is it correct? Kindly confirm

Comment: Yes. You'll need to change the `if s is server_socket` as well, to check if it is one of your sever sockets - which means you'll probably need 2 lists, one with your server sockets, and one with all sockets that you pass to select()

Comment: Kindly provide an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will find a nice explaination here : [Listen to multiple ports from one server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560336/listen-to-multiple-ports-from-one-server). It is for C but the problem in python is the same.

So the answer will be the same :

- one socket per port
- one listen per socket
- a single select

By the way ports below 1024 ar reserved on Unix (and Unix-like) systems : you need root privileges to use them. On Windows, there are no such restrictions.

Comment: My C knowledge is very less. I cannot figure out what actually is happening. Can you please provide a similar kind of code in python. It will be of huge help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second problem - using ports 8000-8100 causes `Invalid argument`, this occurs if you try to rebind an already bound socket without first recreating the socket. There is no problem with that port range however.

```
>>> s=socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('localhost', 8001))
>>> s.bind(('localhost', 8001))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> s.close()
>>> s.bind(('localhost', 8001))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>> s=socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('localhost', 8001))
```

Comment: I understand, but how will I bind `multiple` ports / receive data from multiple ports.?

Comment: I would say: Use multiple instances of SocketServer (or socketserver),  which are bound to different ports, and you bind all of them to the same __handle_callback function.